# Best solution to fetch graphQL data with variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using apollo graphql client with `useQuery` to fetch data with variable, and I'm looking for the best solution to do this.

I want to pass data to one of my components, but my variable user is not yet defined, so I cannot use `useQuery` as expected.

```
  const gqlFoodtruckByUser = gql`
  query Foodtrucks ($user: ID!) {
    foodtrucks (  where: { user: $user }) {
        title
        description
        categorie
        cover {
          url
          name
          provider_metadata
        } 
      }
    }
  `


  const gqlVariables = () => {
  const {user} = useContext(UserContext)  
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(gqlFoodtruckByUser,
    { variables: { user } }
  );

  return (
      <>  {user && 
            <FoodtruckByUser loading={loading} error={error} data={data} user={user.user.id} />
          }
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: use `skip` option, read docs